# SUM() giving same total for all lines, not per each row

Tags: sql, sum

I am having an issue getting some data to display how i want it to.
This is some form of SQL, in software called Cabinet Vision.

What this is supposed to do:
Table 1 is supposed to show 5 CabQty, for CabJob1, and 3 CabQty for CabJob2
Table 1 is currently showing 5 for both CabJob1 and CabJob2

The DoorCount works correctly but the CabCount does not
See Table 1 (Weekly Schedule)
[Weekly Schedule Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVEIC.png)

Below is a screenshot of both of my tables for DoorCount and CabCount, whcih are currently adding them up correctly, but somewhere in the schedule table its almost selecting the TOP CabQty

[Door Count Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKtfp.png)
[Cab Count Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYIoZ.png)

Below is the SQL for each table
------------------ DoorCount SQL

```
SELECT Doors.[Door Num], Doors.[Material Schedule], Doors.[Cabinet ID], 
Count(Doors.[Door Num]) As DoorCount, Doors.[Door Name]

FROM Doors

WHERE Doors.[Door Num] > 0

GROUP BY Doors.[Door Num], Doors.[Material Schedule], Doors.[Cabinet ID], 
Doors.[Door Name]
----------------------

------------------ CabCount SQL
SELECT SUM(Cabinets.Quantity) AS CabQty, [Job Info].[Job Name]

FROM ([Job Info] 
INNER JOIN Rooms ON [Job Info].ID=Rooms.[Job ID]) 
INNER JOIN Cabinets ON Rooms.RoomNumber=Cabinets.[Room ID]

WHERE Cabinets.[Cabinet Name] LIKE 'W1D%' OR Cabinets.[Cabinet Name] LIKE 
't1D%' OR Cabinets.[Cabinet Name] LIKE 'SB%'

GROUP BY [Job Info].[Job Name]
------------------

---------------Weekly Schedule SQL
SELECT  [Job Info].[Job Number], [Job Info].[Customer Name], [Job Info].[Job 
Name], [Job Info].[Customer Comments], DoorCount.[Material Schedule], 
Sum(DoorCount.[DoorCount]) AS DoorCount,  [Job Info].[Customer Email], [Job 
Info].[Customer Fax], [Job Info].[Customer Mobile], [Job Info].[Customer 
Phone], COUNT(CabCount.CabQty) AS CabQty, CabCount.[Job name], Rooms.[Job 
ID]

FROM ((([Job Info]
INNER JOIN Rooms ON [Job Info].ID=Rooms.[Job ID])
INNER JOIN Cabinets ON Rooms.RoomNumber=Cabinets.[Room ID])  
INNER JOIN DoorCount ON Cabinets.[Cabinet ID]=DoorCount.[Cabinet ID])
INNER JOIN CabCount ON [Job Info].[Job Name]=CabCount.[Job Name]

GROUP BY [Job Info].[Job Name], [Job Info].[Job Number], [Job Info]. 
[Customer Name], DoorCount.[Material Schedule],  [Job Info].[Customer 
Comments], [Job Info].[Customer Email], [Job Info].[Customer Fax], [Job 
Info].[Customer Mobile], [Job Info].[Customer Phone], CabCount.[Job name], 
Rooms.[Job ID]

ORDER BY [Job Info].[Customer Email] ASC
---------------------------
```

Thank you for your time and input

Comment: the query says `COUNT(CabCount.CabQty) AS CabQty`. Seems like that should be `CabCount.CabQty AS CabQty`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Is this for Access? always use a tag that tells us the dbms... "sql" isn't sufficient by itself

Comment: Try `MAX( CabCount.CabQty )` instead of a count, but to be honest we really need data, and not images of data (tip: how would you enjoy an image of a solution?)

Comment: Bam, that was the answer J.D,  had been looking at this to long, sorry i cant be more clear because i don't know if its access, and the data i have cant be easily exported into an excel table its internal to the software. This is in a program called Cabinet Vision, it uses some version of SQL
PS. First time asking instead of browsing-- do i upvote or select an answer somehow? Thank you all for your input